# Get shell while installing Ubuntu Server?

Tags: system-installation, luks

I am at the storage layout part of the 20.04 installation. I want to mount an existing luks device with cryptsetup, but I don't see the option in the Custom Storage Layout UI. Is there a way I can get a shell so I can just do the disk manipulation and mounting manually and then just use the installer to choose which devices I want to use?

Comment: The only way you can get that is with the alternate installer.  That will look at existing partitions. I will try to find the link for you.

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04.5-server-amd64.iso  You need the version without "live" in the name.  That will detect existing partitions. There appears to be no such image for 20.04.  You have two options.  Install the 18.04.5 and then immediatly upgrade after install to 20.04.1 or do a normal 20.04.1 install and then add the partitions in later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the install wizard starts, press Alt+F2 to get to a terminal. From here you can run mdadm, crypsetup, lvm, mount and disk formatting commands. When you are done you return to the installer with Alt+F1.

It is important that you do the command line parts before advancing in the installer because the installer does not refresh its view of the disks. If you get to the disk part of the installer and figure out that something is wrong you will need to restart the machine and try again. I could not find a way around this.